# How to hide variables depending on other variables values In Unity inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

how do i hide variables depending on other variables values in the unity inspector. Basically imagine this: if i had a bool called "CanSprint" and a float "SprintSpeed" so i want to make it so that when the bool is true, the float is showing, but when the bool is false, the float hides. This is just to be a little bit neater.
Thanks!

Comment: Hide from where? Show where?

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? In Intelisense? It sounds to me like you have two different classes, one for something that *can* sprint, and one for the other. However they may of course inherit the same base-class.

Comment: I forgot to mention, in the unity inspector, hence the tags

Comment: This has been asked on unity forums -
 https://forum.unity.com/threads/hiding-variables-in-inspector-depending-on-other-variables-value.119906/
Also on Unity answers here - https://answers.unity.com/questions/793852/hiding-or-showing-variables-in-inspector.html and also here - https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/3xc5yo/hide_variables_in_inspector_depending_on_a_bool/

Comment: Thank you!, this is one of the quickest replies i have gotten!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look into custom editor scripts (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html), using a custom editor script you can show variables whenever you like. Here's a layout using the information from the links:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyBehaviourClass))]
public class MyEditorClass : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // If we call base the default inspector will get drawn too.
        // Remove this line if you don't want that to happen.
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        MyBehaviourClass myBehaviour = target as MyBehaviourClass;

        target.myBool = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("myBool", target.myBool);

        if (target.myBool)
        {
            target.someFloat = EditorGUILayout.FloatField ("Some Float:", target.someFloat);

        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to stick this script in the 'Editor' folder, change 'MyBehaviourClass' to your class type, change 'someFloat' to your float and 'myBool' to your boolean variable.

Comment: Thanks, but i have a little question,how to do this with a custom variable, and is it even possible?
Thanks again!

Comment: By custom variable do you mean your own float and bool, or an actual custom data type that you have created?

Comment: If you do mean your own float and bool rather than your own custom data type, you change all occurrences of 'MyBehaviourClass' (including the one above the class definition) to your class type (the one which holds your float and bool), then change 'target.mybool' to 'target.*your bool here*', the same goes for the float.

Comment: i mean something like this a public class with floats and bools and strings,
But how do i do it if there is a array of objects, not just one?

Comment: If you mean that there will be multiple occurrences of 'QuizQuizOption', the editor script will apply its changes to all occurrences of it. Or am I misunderstanding? There is a script in this link which adds support for multiple variables to toggle on and off at once if that is what you mean: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/3xc5yo/hide_variables_in_inspector_depending_on_a_bool/

Comment: Thanks, but i just used Editor.PropertyField (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.PropertyField.html), if anyone in the future finds this page, the code i used is var property = serializedObject.FindProperty("TheNameofTheVariable");
            serializedObject.Update();
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(property, true);"

Answer (score 0):

Use the SetBools Method with HideIf(bool name, bool value, object to hide)

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool exampleBoolA = true;
    public float varToHideA;
    public bool exampleBoolB = false;
    public float varToHideB;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(ExampleClass)), CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class ExampleEditor : Editor
{
    private List<boolStruct> structList;
    public void OnEnable()
    {
        structList = new List<boolStruct>();
        SetBools();
    }
    private void SetBools()
    {
        HideIf("exampleBoolA", false, "varToHideA");
        HideIf("exampleBoolB", true, "varToHideB");
    }
    private void HideIf(string boolName, bool boolValue, string fieldName)
    {
        boolStruct _boolStruct = new boolStruct()
        {
            targetBoolName = boolName,
            targetBoolValue = boolValue,
            targetVarName = fieldName,
        };
        structList.Add(_boolStruct);
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        var obj = serializedObject.GetIterator();
        if (obj.NextVisible(true))
        {
            do
            {
                bool visible = true;
                foreach (var i in structList)
                {
                    if (i.targetVarName == obj.name)
                    {
                        FieldInfo boolName = target.GetType().GetField(i.targetBoolName);
                        var boolValue = boolName.GetValue(target);
                        if (boolValue.ToString() != i.targetBoolValue.ToString())
                            visible = false;
                        else
                        {
                            visible = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (visible)
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(obj, true);
            } 
            while (obj.NextVisible(false));
        }
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
    private struct boolStruct
    {
        public string targetBoolName {get;set;}
        public bool targetBoolValue {get;set;}
        public string targetVarName {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    
    [CustomEditor(typeof(YourClass))]
    [CanEditMultipleObjects]
    public class EditorYourClass : Editor
    {
        // this are serialized variables in YourClass
        SerializedProperty aBool;
        SerializedProperty aFloat;
    
    
        private void OnEnable()
        {
            aBool= serializedObject.FindProperty("aBool");
            aFloat = serializedObject.FindProperty("aFloat");
        }
    
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            serializedObject.Update();
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(aBool);            

            if (aBool.boolValue)
            {                    
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(aFloat);
            }
            
            // must be on the end.
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

            // add this to render base
            base.OnInspectorGUI();
    
        }
    }
```

this (EditorYourClass.cs) must be in unity's Editor folder.
if you inherit from a other class use the inherited class, not the
base class or use this insted:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(YourClass), true)]
```

aFloat field in YourClass.cs should look like this:

```
[SerializeField, HideInInspector] float aFloat;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution, you can just add it to your class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool visible = true;
    public OtherType otherVariable;

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(typeof(MyClass))]
    class MyClassEditor : Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            MyClass self = (MyClass)target;
            serializedObject.Update();
            if (self.visible)
                DrawDefaultInspector();
            else {
                DrawPropertiesExcluding(serializedObject,"otherVariable");
            }
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is really easy even without a custom editor script using the free package [NaughtyAttributes](https://dbrizov.github.io/na-docs/general/installation.html). Just use the [ShowIf/HideIf Attribute](https://dbrizov.github.io/na-docs/attributes/meta_attributes/show_hide_if.html). For your example it could look like this:

```
public class ExampleClass {
    [SerializeField] private bool canSprint;
    [NaughtyAttributes.ShowIf("canSprint")]
    [SerializeField] private float sprintSpeed;
}
```

Of course this can also be done with public variables.

If you would like to hide a variable if a condition is true, just use HideIf instead:

```
public class ExampleClass {
    [SerializeField] private bool isStationaryEnemy;
    [NaughtyAttributes.HideIf("isStationaryEnemy")]
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed;
}
```

This hides movementSpeed, if isStationaryEnemy is true.

The package also supports multiple conditions or enums as conditions, [see docs](https://dbrizov.github.io/na-docs/attributes/meta_attributes/show_hide_if.html).

Answer (score 0):

This helped me with my code, I just added in my Health script.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(typeof(Health))]
    class MyClassEditor : Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            Health self = (Health)target;
            serializedObject.Update();
            if (self.isPlayer)
                DrawPropertiesExcluding(serializedObject, "killScore", "hitScore","dropSpeed","dropMass");

            else
            {
                        DrawDefaultInspector();

                        
            }
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }
#endif
}
```