# Unity - Show Different attributes for different values of another variables in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have something like this:

I have a script attached to a game object. the script has something like below, for example:

```
enum Type {type1, type2};

public Type temptype;

public float F1;
public float F2;
public float F3;
public float F4;
public float F5;
```

in the inspector, when I select "type1" for "temptype" variable, I want to F1, F2 and F3 appear but F4 and F5 be hidden. and when "type2" is selected, F1, F2, F3 hides and F4 and F5 be visible.

this is like "Render Mode" option of canvas component. when we select "screen space - overlay", some variables show in below and when we select "world" some different variables appear.

I don't want to use custom inspector technics. Maybe drawers or property attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide variables depending on other variables values In Unity inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430785/how-to-hide-variables-depending-on-other-variables-values-in-unity-inspector)

Comment: that answer is used the custom editor. I want to do it with Drawers or Attribute properties. this way it could be easier or more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think thats possible without customEditors :/